# How to get rid of weird characters in python string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have lines that contains some pesky control characters:

[image]

When I tried to read the file and then do a `str.replace()`, these control characters didn't get replaced. I've tried this but it's still sticking around.

```
with io.open('infile', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line = line.replace(u'\u0094', '"').replace(u'\u0093', '"').replace(u'\u0092', "'").replace(u'\u0096', '"').replace(u'\u0084', '"')
```

**How do I get these strings replaces? Is there a cannonical way to replace these strings (they look like quotation marks / whitespaces of various kind)?**

What are these characters anyway? What is `u'\u0084'`?

Comment: Can you, instead of a screenshot, provide a sample text? The codes are probably not control characters, but rather typographic quotes etc. Are you sure your input data is UTF-8?

Comment: I agree..please provide sample text

Comment: Have you read any of the million other questions on text encoding/decoding?

Comment: If it's a file you got from a windows computer, it's likely to be saved in Windows-1252 instead of UTF 8, try opening it with that encoding (`"cp1252"`)

Comment: When i copy and pasted the file onto pastebin or a file through the browser, it disappears

Comment: Try different encodings until you find one that displays properly. Replacing the characters will remove valuable data (quotes, single quotes, diacritics, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had that problem, it happened because I was getting characters from outside my ascii range, I had the wrong bounds.